# How to enable FULL Logging with Ganymed SSH-2

Tags: java, ssh, java.util.logging

I am developing a java application that executes ssh commands using `Ganymed SSH-2`

I need to produce full logs for each sequence of commands, e.g. zip file transfer, unzipping, zipping etc..

Having searched the source code for `ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger` i can set the boolean `public static volatile boolean enabled = false;` to true

this provides the following output

```
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: kex_algo=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: server_host_key_algo=ssh-rsa
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: enc_algo_client_to_server=aes128-ctr
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: enc_algo_server_to_client=aes128-ctr
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: mac_algo_client_to_server=hmac-sha1-96
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: mac_algo_server_to_client=hmac-sha1-96
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: comp_algo_client_to_server=none
Mar 05, 2015 10:17:25 AM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger info
INFO: comp_algo_server_to_client=none
```

However I also require ALL level logging for command execution including file transfers.

How do i configure the Logger to produce all the information available?

Comment: When you tell the library to invoke, say, a zip command, you log the fact that you invoked a zip command.

Comment: yes, i can add additional logging, however when i look through the source code of ganymed i can see many degug log statememnts that are not proucing any log output all. how do i enable these log statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late answer but maybe someone still needs this info.

I managed to get the debug statements visible like this:

```
    public void enableFineLogging() {
    try {
        ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger.enabled = true;
        String name = "myDynamicFileNamePart";

        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("./logs/"
                + name + "_SFTP.log", 10000000, 1000, true);
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        fileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());

        final Logger app = Logger.getLogger("ch.ethz");
        app.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        app.addHandler(fileHandler);
        app.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Catchalog
    }
}
```

With result in file with:

> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
>
> INFO: Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0.19.1
>
> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
>
> INFO: Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
>
> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter debug
>
> FINE: Setting <> to `null`
>
> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter debug
>
> FINE: Sending SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
>
> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter debug
>
> FINE: Setting <> to `SOME`
>
> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter debug
>
> FINE: Awaiting <>
>
> marras 15, 2017 12:16:56 IP. org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter debug
>
> FINE: Received SSH_MSG_KEXINIT

Use ConsoleHandler if you wish logs in console.
Also closing the log file needs to be considered with `fileHandler.close()` after you quit logging.

Tune the log level by choosing from `SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST, ALL`